# Elixir List All Modules in Namespace

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on an Elixir/Phoenix app that is intended to create a user in my `UserController` controller. There is a `/lib/helpers/user_helpers` directory with a number of modules (each in a separate file). These modules all have a common namespace `UserHelpers.ModuleName`. In each of these modules I have a function called `apply` which I want to apply to the user data. For example if I have the following file structure:

```
-lib
    -helpers
        -user_helpers
            -module1
            -module2
            -...
            -moduleN-1
            -moduleN
```

where each of `module1` and `module2` contains a function `apply(user_info)` which returns `user_info`. In my `UserController` I have the function `create(conn, params)` in which I want to run the following:

```
user_data
|> UserHelpers.Module1.create
|> UserHelpers.Module2.create
|> ...
|> UserHelpers.ModuleN-1.create
|> UserHelpers.ModuleN.create
```

But I'm unsure how to dynamically load all of the modules in the `UserHelpers` folders to do the above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are these modules compiled into your app (i.e. are they in `.ex` files and not `.exs`)?

Comment: And what order do you want these to be called in? Do the module names end with a number? Is N > 9 (in which case `Enum.sort` would not be enough).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming, that your application is called `:my_app` and helpers have the `.ex` extension and/or explicitly compiled into your application:

```
with {:ok, list} <- :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules) do
  list
  |> Enum.filter(& &1 |> Module.split |> Enum.take(1) == ~w|UserHelpers|)
  |> Enum.reduce(user_data, fn m, acc -> apply(m, :create, acc) end)
end
```

`:application.get_key(:my_app, :modules)` returns the list of modules, known to that application. The second line filters out those unneeded, and the latter one applies their `:create` functions to `user_data` subsequently.

You probably want to embed `Enum.sort` just before the last line to sort the modules to apply in the appropriate order.